# Refused to display index.html because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, content-security-policy

I have a Blazor WebAssembly hosted in ASP.NET Core. For security, I added the following headers:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
      context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
            new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
            {
                  MustRevalidate = true,
                  NoCache = true,
                  NoStore = true,
            };
 
      string oidcAuthority = "https://myidsrv";
      string mainUrl = "https://myurl;
#if DEBUG
      mainUrl = https://localhost:7241;
#endif
 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
        $"default-src 'self' {mainUrl} {oidcAuthority} " +
            "https://code.cdn.mozilla.net" +
            "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com" +
            "'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; " +
        $"script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' {mainUrl}; " +
        $"connect-src 'self' {oidcAuthority} https://code.cdn.mozilla.net;" +
        $"img-src 'self' data {mainUrl}; " +
        $"style-src 'unsafe-inline' {mainUrl} " +
            "https://code.cdn.mozilla.net" +
            ";" +
        "base-uri 'self'; " +
        "form-action 'self'; " +
        "frame-ancestors 'self';");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "same-origin");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Permissions-Policy",
        "geolocation=(), microphone=()");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("SameSite", "Strict");
 
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

When I inspect the website, I see that the `index.html` is not loaded because it doesn't appear in the frame ancestors.

[image]

Although this error, the webapplication is working on Windows but not on iOS.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just logged into your website and found a bug with this image.

[image]

The error you are currently encountering should be a problem with the usage of CSP.

**Solution**

*image*

```
img-src 'self' {mainUrl} data:;
```

*html*

```
script-src 'self' {mainUrl} 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```